# disable crashed application dialog for invoked process

Tags: winapi, windows-7, windows-error-reporting, application-monitoring

I start a process from an application to monitor it.
It may crash or hang.

The monitoring application is prepared for this and can handle this.

But on a crash windows shows a application crash dialog.
At this point the crashed process is still in the process list.
But the dialog does not disappear if the process is going to be terminated by the monitoring app (after timeout with `TerminateProcess`).

I tried to disable the Windows Error Reporting for this application by using the `WerAddExcludedApplication` and `WerRemoveExcludedApplication` but this only removes the option to search online for a solution.

I also do not want to entirely disable WER.

Is there another way to programmatically disable this dialog for a given executable (it will not always be the same)?

Comment: [WerRegisterRuntimeExceptionModule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408167.aspx).

Comment: `SetErrorMode` is inherited, so set the parent's error mode to `SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX` before starting the child.

Comment: changing the ErrorMode Setting does not change anything.

Comment: I use old Visual Studio 2010. For me besides SetErrorMode the old API `_seterrormode(_OUT_TO_STDERR)` (<stdlib.h>) also worked (don't mix it up with _set_error_mode - that one did not work!).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is the `DontShowUI` registry key. This will leave Windows Error Reporting (WER) enabled and simply not pop anything up on an unhanded exception.

DontShowUI (REG_DWORD) Possible values:

0 - UI (default)

1 - No UI (Enable or disable the WER UI)

Link to WER registry settings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638(v=vs.85).aspx

You could set this in the registry here (or also in HKEY_CURRENT_USER):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting]
"DontShowUI"=dword:00000001
```

If you set this key and are still seeing a dialog box on an unhandled exception, I would reccomend searching through the registry for any Value = DontShowUI as  I've sometimes found them set in odd places (and honored by Windows).

Comment: This is a global solution to a local problem.

Comment: Iam with Raymond Chen on this. I does not really want to change the global system behavior. I also stated this in my question.

Comment: Understood. I can't think of great solution in that case. You could set and unset that registry key at certain times during execution, but that's a workaround and not a very good one at that.